# How to dynamically load data in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So i have this page that has the functionality of creating a new course and listing all courses on the same page.

What i want,is when i click on the id of the courses to dynamically load all lessons associated with that id ion a div below that.

this is the index.html.erb of courses

```
<% provide(:title, 'All courses') %>
<h1>All Courses </h1>
<p><%= link_to "Back", admin_path, class: "btn-submit" %></p>

<div class="text-center">
  <%= form_for [:admin, @course] do |f|%>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <p>
    Create a new course
  </p>

    <%= f.label :title%>
    <%= f.text_field :title%>

    <%= f.label :description%>
    <%= f.text_area(:description, size: "24x2") %>

    <%= f.label :duration%>
    <%= f.number_field(:duration, step: 0.5) %>

    <%= f.label :category%>
    <%= f.text_field(:category) %>

    <%= f.label :tag%>
    <%= f.text_field(:tag) %>


    <%= f.submit "Create Course", class: "btn-submit" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<table class="display responsive no-wrap text-center" id="datatableadmin">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Tag</th>
      <th>Deletion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @courses.each do |c| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= c.id %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :title, url: "courses/#{c.id}", cancel_button: 'X' %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :description, url: "courses/#{c.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :duration, url: "courses/#{c.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :category, url: "courses/#{c.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :tag, url: "courses/#{c.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Remove", admin_course_path(c), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="text-center">
  <small style="color:red;">Edit by clicking the fields and pressing enter. Cancel by clicking the X button</small>
</div>
```

so basically if you look down where it says c.id, i want the functionality to call all lessons associated with that id when clicking on that id.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to achieve this, you can prefetch the lessons, and keep them in an hidden `div` and use javascript to unhide them when you click the `id` button or you can use ajax to fetch them from the server when the button is clicked or a combination of both (if you have a large dataset of lessons and you want to lazily load/paginate)

Comment: well even if i load all lessons,i only need those associated with the certain id i click..is there a helpful ajax gem?

Comment: you don't need a gem, when you load lessons, they have information of what `id` they belong to, I am sure you are storing that in the DB, and it would be returned back to the UI, so you would need to store them in a `div` that can be identified (e.g `<div id=lesson1>...</div>`, that way you can use javascript to selectively display what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Cyril DD has ajax solution. I will write pre-fetch solution here. It's recommended to use only when there is a few lessons to fetch,usually not more than 2 digit number. I guess courses aren't that long.

```
<% @courses.each do |c| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="course_id" data-id="<%= c.id %>">
          <%= c.id %>         
        </td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :title, url: "courses/#{c.id}", cancel_button: 'X' %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :description, url: "courses/#{c.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :duration, url: "courses/#{c.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :category, url: "courses/#{c.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place c, :tag, url: "courses/#{c.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Remove", admin_course_path(c), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
///other markups.....
<%= @courses.each do|c| %>
<div id='<%= "lessons_by_course_#{c.id}"%>' class='someClassWithDisplayNone'>
  <%= render partial: "lessons", {locals: {lesson: c.lessons}} %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Then in the javascript

```
$(function(){
  $(".course_id").on("click", function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#lessons_by_course_" + id).removeClass("someClassWithDisplayNone");
  });
})();
```

Of course, this soultion assumes some things such as the existence of a partial `lessons` for rendering lessons(you can write direct markup without partial as well) and the existence of one to many relationship between course and lessons. Otherwise, I believe all code is self explantory.

Comment: thank you for letting me know of such an alternative way it will come in handy for other stuff!

Comment: Hmm I didn't know about this `best_in_place` gem but it looks really cool. However it only supports ActiveRecord apparently so it's dead for mongoid :(. EDIT : nevermind, apparently there's a mongoid fork ;-)

Comment: yeah best in place gem is really awesome and super fast!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the simplest for an AJAX solution is to add a `link_to` to every ID and add the relevant server side code as following.

```
<tbody>
    <% @courses.each do |c| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to(c.id, course_lessons_path(c), remote: :true) %></td>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :courses do
  resources :lessons
end
```

lessons_controller.rb

```
  def index
    find_lessons
    respond_to do |format|
      # Your other formats
      format.js
    end
  end

  def find_lessons
    if params[:course_id]
      @lessons = Course.find(params[:course_id]).lessons
    else
      # Error or @lessons = Lesson.all
    end
  end
```

lessons/index.js

```
var where = $("ul#where-to-load-lesson-id")
where.empty() # Reset list
<% @lessons.each do  |lesson| %>
  # Simple working code
  $('.lessons').append('<li><%= lesson.title %></li>');

  # Advanced code for nested for loops that could use debugging
  # To use if you have nested properties (`lesson has_many exercises`)
  var li = $("<li>", { 
    'class': 'lesson', 
    'html': '<%= lesson.content %>' }
  ).appendTo(where)
  var ex_list = $("<ul>", { 'class': 'exercise-list' }).appendTo(li)
  <% lesson.exercises.each_with_index do |ex, i| %>
      ex_list.append('<li><%= link_to("exercise #{i}", exercice_path(ex)) %></li>');
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i think you wrote it the other way around,access courses from lessons where as i want to access lessons from courses but the idea is the same right?

Comment: i've set it up but nothing seems to work when i click on the id..accessing the url like this "http://localhost:3000/admin/courses/1/lessons" works but clicking on the id,nothing loads up so i assume it has something to do with the javascript/ajax request

Comment: i've managed to get correct response but its not appending in my courses view

Comment: Check the javascript is not bugged. If you are using firefox, open the debugger, In the console tab, check for your AJAX request. Click on it to unwrap, then switch to the response sub-tab. Copy everything. Then, paste it on the console (the bottom line) and click execute. If you find the error(s), feel free to edit my post or write a comment.

Comment: i have used chrome to see the ajax responses and i was getting errors,i fixed your code but again it wont append for some reason

Comment: Alright, well I saw you were able to find a working code anyways. I remember struggling for quite some time when I had to append and select elements I just appended (nested `for` loops), which is why I showed you this syntax, but then yours seem more simple. I'll make a final edit.

Comment: ah i see,well you should also edit the route path as lesson_courses_path points to course controller index action, and for this implementation the path should be course_lessons_path to use the lessons_controller index action..

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Cyril DD response this is what correctly worked as there where some issues with Cyrils code.

in my courses/index.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to(c.id, admin_course_lessons_path(c), remote: :true) %></td>

at the bottom i have
<ul class="lessons"></ul>
```

in my routes.rb

```
resources :lessons do
  resources :courses
end
```

in my lessons_controller.rb

```
def index
    find_lessons
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def find_lessons
       if params[:course_id]
         @lessons = Course.find(params[:course_id]).lessons
       else
         @lessons = Lesson.all
         @lesson = Lesson.new
       end
   end
```

in my index.js.erb file inside admin/lessons/ folder

```
$('.lessons').empty();
<% @lessons.each do |l| %>
$('.lessons').append('<li><%= l.title %></li>');
<% end %>
```